# Showing that $A/I$ is an algebra over a field $K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

Let $A$ be a $K$-Algebra with $1_A \in A$ and $I \subset A$ an ideal.

The definition I use is: An algebra over a field $K$ is a ring $A$ which is also a $K$-vector space and satisfies $a \cdot (\lambda b)=(\lambda a) \cdot b= \lambda (ab) \ \forall \lambda \in K, \ \forall a,b \in A$.

How to show that the quotient ring $A/I$ is also a $K$-Algebra?

My way was to show the following identities:

$\forall x,y,z \in A/I, \ \forall \lambda \in K$ it's:

$1) (x+y)z=xz+yz$

$2) x(y+z)=xy+xz$

$3) \ \lambda(xy)=(\lambda x)y=x(\lambda y)$

So for $1)$:

$((a+ I)+(b+I))\cdot (c+I)=((a+b)+I)\cdot(c+I)=(a+b)\cdot c+I= ac+bc+I=(a+I)(c+I)+(b+I)(c+I)$

$2)$:

$(a+I)\cdot((b+I)+(c+I))=(a+I)\cdot((b+c)+I)=a(b+c)+I=ab+ac+I=(a+I)(b+I)+(a+I)(c+I)$

$3)$:

$\lambda((a+I)(b+I))=(\lambda (a+I))(b+I)=(a+I)(\lambda (b+I))$

Since $A/I$ holds all 3 identities it's a $K$-algebra.

Is this the right way to show that $A/I$ is a $K$-Algebra or is there another way to show it?

Comment: What definition of $K$-algebra are you using?

Comment: The definition I use is: An algebra over a field $K$ is a ring $A$ which is also a $K$-vector space and satisfies $a \cdot (\lambda b)=(\lambda a) \cdot b= \lambda (ab) \ \forall \lambda \in K,\ \forall a,b \in A$.

Comment: I strongly recommend using a different notation for elements of $A/I$. Use something like $\bar a$ instead of $a+I$. Otherwise calculations will look messy and be hard to follow, since expressions like $(a+I)+(b+I)$ contain multiple instances of $+$ whose meanings are different. Not to mention how long even simple expressions like the sum or product of two elements become.